# Sec-WebSocket-Accept mismatch

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

I am currently developing a WebSocket server in Python but I am not able to calculate the Sec-WebSocket-Accept apparently, which is not very difficult normally.
Here is my function to calculate this (written in Python) :

```
def get_accept_websocket_key(self, key):
    magic_string = '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11'
    key += magic_string
    return base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha1(key).hexdigest())
```

All my results seems to be good but I always have in the javascript console :

> Error during WebSocket handshake: Sec-WebSocket-Accept mismatch

Have you any solution?

Thank you.

Comment: which browser are you using as your client?

Comment: Google Chrome 18.0.1025.168 under Ubuntu. ;-)

Comment: so you're implementing the RFC 6455 version of the specification?

Comment: I found the solution... I need to use digest() instead of hexdigest(), my bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working example.
Lookup at code with "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol"

```
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from hashlib import sha1

def sendHeaers(self, connect)
    data = ["HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols",
            "\r\nUpgrade: websocket",
            "\r\nConnection: Upgrade"]

    if 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' in self.httpHeader:
        data.append("\r\nSec-WebSocket-Protocol: webserver")

    if 'Sec-WebSocket-Key' in self.httpHeader:
        sha1f = sha1()
        sha1f.update(self.httpHeader['Sec-WebSocket-Key'] + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11")
        ticket = b64encode(sha1f.digest())
        data.append("\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: " + ticket)

    data.append("\r\n\r\n")
    connect.send( "".join(data) )
```